# How to insert in MySQL at the same second

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to insert a row into mysql at the same second, I have a simple for loop which inserts date into mysql.

This for loop takes 12 seconds because it has to loop 12 times. And my MySQL Database shows each row at different second.

I want to insert multiple rows at the same second, I know I might not get all of the 12 rows at the same time but want to see how many rows can be inserted to my database via my function at the same time.

Here is my function.

```
    $ddos=new DDOSManager();
    //This is my library/class.
    echo 'Start: '. date('H:m:s',time()).'<br>';
    for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
        //In this function the data is being inserted to the database, via Laravel Eloquent.
        $ddos->TrackDOS($data);
    }
    return date('H:m:s',time());
```

Comment: Your loop takes 1 second per iteration? You must have a really slow system.

Comment: Why not insert the 12 rows in a single `INSERT` statement ?

Comment: @roberto06 I am checking in-app DOS Attack (usuage of a paricular feature inside an application). Can't do that.

Comment: Ok thats confusing, first of all it doesn't take more than 1 micro sec to insert a mysql record so I am guessing you have some logic which takes time in your TrackDOS function in your model. Second, you said you want to insert multiple rows at same second then why you cant use insert? it does same thing. Please add more details to clarify your question.

Comment: Please, post the code of `TrackDOS` function.